# Ant - check node exist in a xml file

Tags: xml, xslt, ant

I have ant target which get a sequence of xml files and transform to html using xslt.

Sample input files:

```
<doc>
    <national>
        <doc-type>nat</doc-type>
    </national>
    <section>
        <para>text</para>
    </section>
</doc>
```

or

```
<doc>
    <regional>
        <doc-type>reg</doc-type>
    </regional>
    <section>
        <para>text</para>
    </section>
</doc>
```

After running the ant file, these documents should be transformed to html. (transform is already written using xslt)

Sample output:

```
<html>
    <head>nat</head>
    <body>text</body>
</html>
```

This is my ant part target,

```
<macrodef name="transform-to-html">
  <attribute name="xml"/>

  <sequential>
    <local name="filename"/>
    <basename file="@{xml}" property="filename" suffix=".xml"/>

    <echo>Source:  @{xml}</echo>

    <xmltask source="@{xml}">
        <copy path="//national//doc-type/text()" property="national-exists"/>
        <copy path="//regional//doc-type/text()" property="regional-exists"/>
        <copy path="//international//doc-type/text()" property="international-exists"/>
    </xmltask>

    <local name="html"/>

    <property name="html" location="${temp.html.dir}/${filename}.html"/>

    <if>
    <isset property="national-exists"/>
    <then>
        <transform input="@{xml}" xsl="${national.xsl.file}" output="${html}" catalog="${html.catalog.file}" />
    </then>
    <isset property="regional-exists"/>
    <then>
        <transform input="@{xml}" xsl="${regional.xsl.file}" output="${html}" catalog="${html.catalog.file}" />
    </then>
    <isset property="international-exists"/>
    <then>
        <transform input="@{xml}" xsl="${international.xsl.file}" output="${html}" catalog="${html.catalog.file}" />
    </then>
  </if>

  </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

this retrieve sequence of xml files and transform using ${html.xsl.file} to html format.

in input xml file i have 3 categories.

1. has `<national>` node in the content
2. has `<regional>` node in the content
3. has `<international>` node in the content

what I need is if input xml has `<national>` node it has to run with national.xsl file, if input xml has `<regional>` node it has to run with regional.xsl and if input xml has `<international>` node it has to run with international.xsl.

But this fails, given error message is 'The property name is undefined'..
Any suggestion how can I fix this issue, or can anyone suggest how to check if a specific node exists in a xml document using ant.

Comment: It would be helpful and handy for others in the community if you can edit the question add sample input and desired output.

Comment: Can you attach the `.xsl` files too?